# Upload images directly from an Angular application to AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am currently following [this](https://medium.com/ramsatt/angular-7-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-bucket-ba27022bad54) tutorial to upload an image directly from my angular application onto an AWS S3 bucket. I made some minor changes to sort out the few errors that came up during my execution, however when I run my code I find that the function I use to select the image ("selectFile()") is not being executed when I click the button.

The code in my appcomponent.ts file is as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedFiles: any = '';  //In the tutorial it was selectedFiles: FileList; But it kept throwing errors.
  imageSrc: string = '';

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  upload() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.uploadService.uploadFile(file);
  }
  
  selectFile(event: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      console.log(file.name);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageSrc = reader.result as string;
      }
      this.selectedFiles = file;
    }
  }
}
```

UploadService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {

  constructor() { }

  uploadFile(file: any) {
    const contentType = file.type;
    const bucket = new S3({
      accessKeyId: '...',
      secretAccessKey: '...',
      region: '...'
    });
    const params = {
      Bucket: '...',
      Key: file.name,
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: contentType
    };
    bucket.upload(params, function(err: any, data: any){
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
    });
    //for upload progress   
    /*bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.loaded + ' of ' + evt.total + ' Bytes');
      }).send(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
    });*/
  }
}
```

And AppComponent.html is below:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
  <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc" style="width:100%">
  <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
</label>

<button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So anyone is able to read the credentials from the javascript files and upload whatever they want?

Comment: I couldn't find a better alternative, and was told this got the job done. So went ahead with it, considering that it'd only be used to post basic images as part of a small project.

Comment: Beware of the warning at the top of the page in the link you have provided:     **!!!! Alert: High security risk in this kind of approach. We will come with new one soon. Please don't follow this now.!!!**

Comment: "considering that it'd only be used to post basic images as part of a small project"  If you give the world AWS credentials, you will find they will be used for much more than that.  It is a very bad idea to find out what happens.

Comment: So is there a different approach to this then? How do I upload images onto my S3 bucket from my angular app and how can I retrieve them for display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the first file out of the file list twice:

```
const [file] = event.target.files; // taking the first file
```

and then again inside the `upload` function:

```
const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
```

Also, it looks like you're mixing `this.selectedFiles` (which the name and your tutorial imply should be a list of files, and for some reason you're intializing it to an empty string!) and you assign to it type File inside `selectFile`.

I think it would be better to work with strong types, where I would change the .html and .ts as below:

.html:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
  <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc" style="width:100%">
  <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event.target.files)">
</label>

<button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFileToUpload" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

and .ts:

```
private selectedFileToUpload: File = null;

public upload() {
    if (!this.selectedFileToUpload) {
        alert('Please select a file first!'); // or any other message to the user to choose a file
        return;
    }

    this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.selectedFileToUpload);
}

public selectFile(filesList: FileList) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    const fileToUpload = filesList.item(0);

    console.log(fileToUpload.name);
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileToUpload);
    reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageSrc = reader.result as string;
    };

    this.selectedFileToUpload = fileToUpload;
}
```

Note,

> however when I run my code I find that the function I use to select the image ("selectFile()") is not being executed when I click the button.

The `selectFile` function should not be executed when you click the upload button! The `selectFile` function will be executed every time you change a file in the selected files, and in the example I wrote (not tested) it should save a reference to the file you want to upload. Then, the `Upload` button would only trigger the `upload` function that would take the same reference to the selected file and pass it to the upload service to be uploaded by the s3 package.

Again, I didn't test the code, but I tried to help by fixing your logic.